# Como agrupar resultados de uma query?

Tags: php, sql, select

Tenho a seguinte consulta que traz o nome da receita e os ingredientes:

```
$query = ("
SELECT r.receita, i.ingrediente
FROM ptp_receitas r, ptp_receitas_ingredientes ri, ptp_ingredientes i
WHERE r.id = ri.idreceita
AND ri.idingrediente = i.id
AND r.id = ".$rid);
$db -> setQuery($query);
$results = $db -> loadObjectList();
foreach($results as $row){
    echo '<h1>'.$row->receita.'</h1>';
    echo '<h2>Lista de Ingredientes:</h2>';
    echo $row->ingrediente;

}
```

O problema é que desse jeito ele repete o nome da receita em todas as linhas do ingrediente, por exemplo:

```
Receita de Arroz
arroz
Receita de Arroz
sal
```

Eu queria que viesse:

```
Receita de arroz
arroz
sal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça a seguinte lógica com uma variável auxiliar que irá resolver seu problema:

```
$query = ("
SELECT r.receita, i.ingrediente
FROM ptp_receitas r, ptp_receitas_ingredientes ri, ptp_ingredientes i
WHERE r.id = ri.idreceita
AND ri.idingrediente = i.id
AND r.id = ".$rid);
$db -> setQuery($query);
$results = $db -> loadObjectList();

$count = 0;
foreach($results as $row){
    if($count != $row->idreceita){
        echo '<h1>'.$row->receita.'</h1>';
        echo '<h2>Lista de Ingredientes:</h2>';
        $count=$row->idreceita;
    }
    echo $row->ingrediente;

}
```

Dessa forma, irá imprimir `<h1> Nome da Receita</h1>` e a linha do `<h2>` apenas 1x por receita.

Comment: Perfeito, só alterei o idreceita por id e coloquei o r.id no SELECT. Valeu!!!

Comment: Beleza! Que bom que deu certo ;)